# Ряд Тейлора, написал как знаю, кому не трудно гляньте плз

Tags: c, математика, ряды, численные-методы

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 


double f(long n, long x) {
    long tt = (2*n)+1;
    long b = 1, c;
    double res;
    res = pow(x, (2*n+1));
    res *= (double)pow(-1, n);
    if (tt >= 0 && tt <= 12) {
        for (c = 1; c <= tt; c++) {
            b = b * c;
        }
    }
    res = res / b;
    return res;
}
int main()
{

    float e;
    scanf("%f\n", &e);

    long double previous, current;
    long double sum = 0;
    long n, x, tt, a;
    printf("\nn = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nx = ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    current = f(n, x); // значение n-го ряда члена
    sum = sum + current;
    n++;
    do {
        previous = current;
        current = f(n, x);
        sum = sum + current;
        n++;

    } while (fabs(current - previous) > e);
    printf("\nsum = %lf\n", sum);
_getch();
```

Comment: `e=-25` и `abs` - ???

Comment: вроде бы исправил

Comment: я верно все рассчитал или есть косяки?

Comment: Почему `x` вдруг оказался целочисленным?

Answer (score 4):

Простите уж, но столько ошибок, что не исправить. Вы зачем-то вводите и точность, и число членов ряда, вычисляете каждый член ряда с какими-то извращениями в части вычисления факториала, с неверным условием цикла (и неверно используемым n)...

Странная смесь `float` и `long double` (последний, кстати, можно не трогать - как минимум в VC++, которым вы пользуетесь, он не отличается от `double`). Аргумент синуса (надеюсь, вы в курсе, что этот ряд вычисляет `sin(x)`?) не обязательно целочисленный...

Простите уж, сначала пытался исправлять ваше творчество, но потом решил написать [свое](https://ideone.com/yOgrmw), так проще.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double S(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = x, term = x;
    for(int n = 0;fabs(term) > eps;++n)
        sum += term *= -x*x/(2*n+2)/(2*n+3);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const double eps = 1e-8;
    printf(" x       S(x)       sin(x)\n---------------------------\n");
    for(double x = 0.0; x < 1.6; x += 0.1)
        printf("%3.1lf   %.7lf   %.7lf\n",x,S(x,eps),sin(x));
}
```

Comment: @Igor.c Вы что, всерьез ожидали, что за вас тут будут полностью программы писать?! Неужели вы такой альтернативно одаренный, что не в состоянии взять **готовую функцию**, ввести что надо и ее вызвать?! Как мёд - так ложкой?!